# E-R model for budget app

Tags: database-design

I'm going to **build small budgeting application**. There should be monthly budget and planned costs to be planned. This is simple one-to-many relationship. OK. But what about fact expenses? What is best practices for **setting fact table(s)** for catching **actual expenses**?

*Should I use the same table as for planned ones but set its property to 'Fact' and use child-parent relationship within single table?* Should I use other table(s) (and app entities of course) to gather actual data from user? How to relate those table in this case?

Could someone point me to some theory about the subject?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building an application, then you probably don't want a Fact table at all. Fact tables are a part of star schemas, which are used in data warehouses and data marts for reporting and analytics purposes.

I would suggest you look into data modelling topics like conceptual modelling, logical modelling, and normalisation. A normalised schema (third normal form or higher) is far more suitable for a transactional system.

If you then also want to provide reporting and analysis functionality after you get the transactional system working, the usual pattern is to populate a data mart (which may well use Facts, Dimensions, etc.) from the application's database.

Comment: Thank you, Jo, for reply! I understand what fact table is in terms of DWH since I'm building a little SSAS models, using SSIS to load data and SSRS to build reports. I also know what is 3NF. I probably confuse you with those definitions used in my questions. I understand that I need OLTP database. But I do not get an idea how properly build its schema to catch not only planned but actual expenses. What entities and relationships should I use to follow best practices - that is the question I need an answer for.